# iOS MKMapView not displaying map in the simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, mkmapview, mapkit

I've just started learning iOS development for iPhone, and following a couple of examples regarding how to display a mapView with the `MapKit Framework`, I found that google map tiles are not displayed, I only get an empty view (grey tiles), at least in the iPhone simulator (I haven't tried on a device).

I also get this error message:

> /SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps_Sim/GoogleMobileMaps-363.1.2/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:235
>   server returned error: 403

I found solutions for similar problem when developing for Android, but not for iOS. Could somebody help me with this issue? Adding the `MapKit` framework to the project is supposed to be enough to get this working, or maybe am I missing some extra settings that are not mentioned in the tutorials I've followed?

Thanks!

This is the simple sample code I used:

```
// ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@end


// ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapView=_mapView;

- (void)viewDidUnload {
   [super viewDidUnload];
   [self setMapView:nil];
}
... more methods...
```

And in .xib file, I connected a `MKMapView` to the file's owner mapView outlet. And at this point, according to the tutorial, I am supposed to be able to see a default US map when running the simulator, but I'm always getting the error I posted before at the debug area, and map view displays only the grey empty grid.

Comment: Post your code please. It will be easier to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - my `UIMapView` was only showing the grid, but not the actual map. I quit the simulator and then launched the project again - now it showed the map! It seems like iOS simulator does loses the connection sometimes, even though you might be connected on your computer. 
Thank you all for your input!

Comment: You might want to consider more detailed input than 'turn it off and on again'.  A more detailed explanation of how you prevented the problem from re-occurring is a much better standard of solution than finding a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the delegate to files owner(self)?
Also have you included mapkit framework and the related header files?

Comment: The mapView seems to "work", I mean, if I draw a pin on the map (or where I was supposed to see a map), the pin is displayed... it looks like the map tiles are simply not loaded. I only see the pin, the empty map view and the google logo

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, my iOS simulator sometimes just loses connection to the internet (my computer has connection, but the simulator doesn't recognize it).  Once I quit and relaunched my simulator, my maps started showing.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS simulator comes with the official maps app included. Open that and verify that it can get tiles, it could be a network issue. Without any code, outlets, delegates or anything the map should show map data.

Comment: I've just installed Google Maps app and it loads the tiles... what could be happening?

Comment: I just saw this behavior today. I also ran the Maps app, and it did not draw any tiles. Any idea what that was?

Comment: @DanMorrow If the Maps app isn't showing any tiles then you have network issues.

Comment: @Craig - I wish it were that easy. I've got great connectivity. Very fast connections. The map fails to draw in two different locations right now (work and home). Don't know what to do here.

My phone, which on the same network as my Mac, draws the map perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

An empty map view (grey tiles) as you've described I have seen on the iPhone simulator and a device when trying to specify a map region (see code below for example), however the user has not granted access to their location in app settings. Removing this piece of code when running on the simulator resolved the issue.

```
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
mapRegion.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
[self.mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone looking for the solution. Network issue is solely responsible for this issue. Make sure your simulator has network connection and if it is able to load default apple map, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a little bit tricky because it involves lots of cases, but for me, it was not loading because of the network monitoring application, eg. `Charles`, make sure that you have an internet connection and it's unmonitored

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by connecting to WIFI with my phone. I didn't have a SIM card installed in my phone, so it just showed the tiles. Just make sure you have network connection.